# How to erase all session contents on disk, without re-setting the cookie or destroying or renewing the session_id?

Tags: php, session, cookies

If I run session_start(), PHP sets the header:

```
Set-Cookie: PHPSESSID=8eaob23kepcehbl82ie4sj7897; expires=Fri, 24-Oct-2014 13:45:20 GMT; path=/
```

If I want to session_destroy() (during a logout or login, for example), PHP further adds to the previous with headers:

```
Set-Cookie: PHPSESSID=nv7ebf0sbkeg7cv0o45pb5hru1; expires=Fri, 24-Oct-2014 13:45:20 GMT; path=/
```

This seems to indicate that a lot of session files are being created or left as unused garbage around, and looking at the sess_ files, this is seems to be very true. I want to minimize this, and create one session file (and hence one session id) per user, and stick to it forever. Common usage tells me that this behavior is kind of what PHP is expecting.

But I still want to have a safe and secure session destruction function, for cases where I logout/login. So how do I erase all session contents in the session file on disk, without destroying/resetting/re-starting the session, which may cause a new session file to be started?

Comment: As session files are cleaned up automatically all you will really achieve by doing this is lowering security whilst saving a very minimal amount of disk space unless you make a habit of storing vast amounts of information in each users session.

Comment: I agree, but that does not answer the question.

Comment: That is why this was a comment and not an answer

Comment: what do you actually want? Less session files but varying session ids, or fixed session ids, which means vastly more session files plus completely unnecessary security risks

Answer (score 0):

You may want to have a look at the [php.ini](http://php.net/manual/en/ini.list.php) session directives to tweak the session cleanup process.

[session.gc_probability](http://php.net/manual/en/session.configuration.php#ini.session.gc-probability) :

> session.gc_divisor coupled with session.gc_probability defines the probability that the gc (garbage collection) process is started on every session initialization. The probability is calculated by using gc_probability/gc_divisor, e.g. 1/100 means there is a 1% chance that the GC process starts on each request. session.gc_divisor defaults to 100.

[session.gc_maxlifetime](http://php.net/manual/en/session.configuration.php#ini.session.gc-maxlifetime) :

> session.gc_maxlifetime specifies the number of seconds after which data will be seen as 'garbage' and potentially cleaned up. Garbage collection may occur during session start (depending on session.gc_probability and session.gc_divisor).

But usually php's default session cleanup settings are fine.

If you want to delete the content of a specific session file, there does not seem to exist an easy way to do it. If you are so concerned about accessing the files, you could change the [session.save-path](http://php.net/manual/en/session.configuration.php#ini.session.save-path) to another location and restrict access only to the user running php.

An alternative would be to store only the user id in the php session and all other data in a database (or even in a file if no database is available and there are not too many users) with the user id as primary key. There you have your fixed id for each user and also full control what data to persist and to erase when the user logs out. So you don't have to worry about data in session files.

Comment: This lets PHP cleaning up the session files that are not being used, but I have no problem with that (as you mentioned), and that doesn't really resolve my problem: How can you wipe out the *contents* of a *single, specific* session file (using a known session_id) ?